# Can we have the action potential an AC current

Tags: ac, biopotential

as well known brain are connected to our body by neuronal cells. it transmits and receives its data by action potential during neuronal cells. i wonder if any one can explain to me the properties of this current. can we consider this current as a AC current?

Comment: Depends what you are considering AC. DC can be considered AC as well. Just having a zero amplitude and a non-zero offset.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a biomedical, not an electrical engineering question. Also, lacks research, since [wikipedia explains everything pretty well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_potential#Process_in_a_typical_neuron) and OP didn't take any reference to literature.

Comment: I gave up at the start of the second sentence.  Closing due to sloppiness, and -1 for the disrespect.

Comment: @MarcusMüller -- sure, rain on my parade!

Comment: @ScottSeidman sorry :D yeah, the way you represented it, your **answer** has a lot of engineering value. Great answer! Not quite sure it makes the question better :) Can you actually enrich the question? That would make it easier to retract my close vote, emotionally! (saying you can would do that, already, no need to hurry)

Comment: @Alirahmani Please punctuate and format your questions correctly.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  -- not a bad idea.  I might come back to it, then pass the hat for reopen votes.

Comment: @Scott: You could ask your own question for which your existing answer is well suited, then copy it there.  That's better than trying to make this turkey of a question hop along.  The question was closed for good reason.  This is the second time this OP has written a crappy question in a day.  Last time a misguided do-gooder fixed it for him, so he didn't learn any lesson from it.  There needs to be a cost for dumping crap on us, else too many people won't take quality seriously.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the nature of the cell membrane, which is permeable to some ions and impermeable to others, the cell is at a Nernst equilibrium, which is a chemical engineering concept in which electrical forces on ions balance with those due to  concentration gradients.  The resting membrane potential is near the Nernst potential of Potassium ion, as at rest the membrane is most permeable to potassium.

The trick behind the action potential is that there are voltage-mediated ion channels.  Most specifically, when a small injection of current makes the cell membrane move in a positive direction, it becomes more permeable to sodium ion, which makes the inside of the cell move in a more positive direction, and makes it even more permeable to sodium, and so on and so on, in a positive feedback loop.  Eventually, the membrane gets very near the Nernst potential of sodium ion.  Then, potassium channel start opening and sodium channels start shutting, bringing the cell back to resting potential

[image] -- from http://slideplayer.com/slide/8690401/26/images/18/The+Action+Potential+is+Generated+by+Sequential+Activation+of+gNa+and+gK.jpg

The process is often expressed as the *Parallel Conductance Model*:
[image]  -- From http://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F915%2F915975a0-b751-48de-9ade-dee95fa25a46%2Fphpot2y0T.png

The values of the batteries correspond to the Nernst potentials of the respective ionic species -- which is the value at which current of the ion due to electrical forces is equal and opposite to current due to the concentration gradient for  a given species.

Though resting potential is about -70mV, the action potential is mostly an AC signal, with frequency components well into the kHz range.